# Is there a name for the inverse of the impostor syndrome?

Tags: terminology

**Question:** The [impostor syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome) seems to be common in academia and there are quite a few questions about it. I wonder if there is something like the inverse impostor syndrome.

I'm not referring to the [Dunning–Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect), I don't feel particularly superior to anyone. That's not it. Metaphorically: I don't feel like I have a greater slice of cake because I don't see any cake, even though everybody speaks about how big, moist and delicious their slices are and how knowledgeable they are about cakes.

To me, **everybody feels like an impostor**. (And everything feels like a lie)

Is there a name for this feeling? I deeply and seriously wonder about how accurate and shared it may be, if it has a name then most likely I'm not alone in this and therefore maybe I would not be completely mistaken.

**End of the question.**

**Examples** (in case you need them, I work in computer science):

- Head of the department speaking about "big data" for an excel file of several megabytes.
- Planning setting the deadlines looking exclusively at the calendar (and not the work).
- Gantt where activity A ends before activity B starts. A requires B.
- Becoming an expert on a topic overnight because it's trendy and a buzzword.
- Correcting English grammar and paper structure, for the worse.
- Paper reporting evaluation results before any code has been written.
- Paper reporting evaluation results when the code does a different thing.
- Coauthoring a paper, without even laying their eyes on it.
- Directing a thesis, not checking the formulas, only the "easy" parts.
- A researcher makes the GUI, gets all the credit.
- Constant meetings with no agendas or minutes (or effects)
- Micromanaging without actual managing
- Powerpoint before actual research or Powerpoint instead any research
- Re-selling old ideas with new labels and minor cosmetic changes that are for the worse
- Most of the tweets with the tag #overlyhonestmethods. However that's being sloppy, I mean being an impostor, focusing solely on how things look because:

  - Doing some research formally (writing proofs) and empirically (developing a system and testing it with a benchmark, creating a benchmark!) and writing about it on a paper takes much longer than
  - Writing some fiction on a paper, which anyway takes much longer than
  - Subliminally collaborating on a paper and putting your name in it.

BTW: one of the problems why there are so many impostors (as I see it) is that open source code is not requested.

Comment: _Powerpoint before actual research or Powerpoint instead any research_ — If I had a nickel ...

Comment: I honestly didn't know whether I should flag this as *too broad*, *off-topic* or *primarily opinion-based*. In the end, I went with *too broad*.

Comment: Welcome to earth.  There are humans here.  Many of them live with their flaws and foibles.  Some of them might call you autistic or anal-retentive.  Whether they're right or not, continue to live life according to your values.  If you have boundless energy and resources, you can attempt conversion of them.

Comment: That question comes suspiciously close to a rant, but I think the actual question ("how is it called if I think everybody is just making shit up?") is interesting.

Comment: Do you feel like *you* are doing the best work you are capable of? I try to refrain from armchair psychology, but I wouldn't be surprised if a few years of internalized guilt lead to strong cynical feelings.

Comment: @xLeitix: But that question is rather more about psychology, and hasn't really got anything to do with academia.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about psychology.

Comment: @NateEldredge "Hasn't got anything to do with academia" is too strong a statement. I would really want to keep this question around, I think it is much too important.

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with the imposter syndrome, or the inverse thereof.

Comment: +1 because to me, almost everybody feels like an imposter.

Comment: While the question is pretty opinionated the share number of answers and comments show it touches a real, existing problem in academia. Good examples, by the way.

Comment: Can your second paragraph be summarized, "**the cake is a lie**?" :)

Comment: I'm curious, do you really mean *everyone* seems like an impostor?  It would help if you could clarify that.  I certainly share your disappointment frequently, and your laundry list is spot on-- on the other hand there are people and actions I've seen that inspire me greatly and give me hope that we can do better.  Do you share that perception at all?

Comment: I propose a name for it: **outposter syndrome**

Comment: Congratulations: you have just discovered that your department is a microcosm of American politics. Virtually every flaw on your bulleted list (and the overarching disillusionment) seems applicable to our government in some way.

Comment: I call it "drinking the kool-aid".  If I have time I'll write about the phenomenon in an answer.

Comment: The list of bad behavior doesn't sound like everybody 'feels' like an impostor. You are saying that you think everybody *is* an impostor.

Comment: @Jigg I *think* many things but here I wanted to focus on what I *perceive*. I perceive a lot of talking, very little making and strong discrepancies between what is said to be done and what is actually done, i.e. pretending. Moreover, I perceive greater success and success opportunities based mostly on pretending, as opposed to real merit. Of course I can be completely mistaken.

Comment: Research used to be a calling (or an expensive hobby for aristocrats) now it's a career like any other. The goal is to secure your position, make cash, and access to higher social status. As the whole thing is mostly state-funded, it's inevitable that the system is political/corrupt/etc. I'm blessed to be in a research group where *the actual science* is the primary objective, but I know not everyone is...

Comment: 'success and success opportunities based mostly on pretending, as opposed to real merit' what was a real relief to me is that in fact, if you have actual merit, you can be successful as well.

Comment: Not relevant to your actual question, but the inverse of the impostor syndrome is probably technically the [Capgras syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capgras_delusion) where you mistakenly believe someone else is an impostor.

Comment: Common naïve youth, before self-realization? The naivety being that you don't (yet) realize your own shortcomings and weaknesses because you are still conditioned by a educational system that focuses on so heavily on promoting success and unending competition. Potentially _dysthymia_ if not school specific. Or merely your coming of age as a curmudgeon.

Comment: Have you forwarded this to The Professor is In?    In other words, welcome to academia.

Comment: Isn't this just becoming skeptical of people?

Comment: What does this have to do with academics?

Comment: @bmargulies the impostor syndrome is usual among academics, both the original and the "inverse" in this question may be related with the peer review, academics are mostly judged only by other academics, which may lead to some [Emperor's New Clothes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_New_Clothes) effect and ad verecundiam fallacies, among others. I guess [academicians would hope](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) something better from research but given how everything is structured maybe we should not expect nothing much better (except for coincidences).

Comment: **Walk away.** If what you describe is as common in your department as you think it is, you should seriously consider changing departments, or changing fields, or leaving academia entirely. It really is not this bad everywhere.

Comment: @JeffE I'm on it.

Comment: have you read the book "Catcher in the Rye"?

Comment: @J.Roibal nope, do you think that there is something to highlight from it?

Comment: @Trylks what you are describing (a feeling that most people are full of BS) is a feeling shared by the protagonist of the group, 'Holden Caulfield'. It may benefit you to read the book, if for no other reason, than to be able to relate to a character who is experiencing a similar point of view. Here is a link to the wikipedia article about Catcher in the Rye: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Catcher_in_the_Rye

Answer (score 55):

I have on occasion felt the same myself (sometimes still do), and know of many disillusioned PhD students who felt exactly like that. There are dark moments in the night, when you are wondering whether funding for CS will be cut down entirely eventually, when funding agencies also get to the conclusion that CS is one big science of imposters.

However, what you need to realize is that this **is in fact impostor syndrome** - only that you are not comparing yourself to your peers, but rather you *and* your peers to e.g., other sciences. However, the reason why it happens are the same: you have unrealistically high expectations of the research community, which it cannot possibly live up to in reality. You know the shortcomings of your community all too well, but do not have enough insight to see that other research communities or professions are also far from perfect. Yes, all the crap you mention happens on occasion, but guess what? We are all human, so it is simply unrealistic to assume that every professor will always be a good manager (or even a decent human being), that every dean will always still be an active and good researcher, or that every paper is always published with the most noble intentions.

I should also mention that your conclusion that, if you are not alone in this feeling, you surely need to be right, is fundamentally flawed. History has shown all over again that *many* people can be wrong in the same way at the same time.

**Edit:**

By the way, I think your question title is wrong. The opposite of the impostor syndrome is, as you say, more or less the Dunning–Kruger effect. What you are referring to is not the opposite.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that this is still imposter syndrome, but just at a different scale (collective, rather than individual, and perhaps not applying to all memebers of the collection).

Comment: I fully agree with the "you're not referring to the opposite of IS" part

Comment: Brilliant observation that it can be framed as impostor syndrome on a larger scale... on the other hand, the difference between "impostor syndrome" and "observation that I/we/many-of-us are impostors" is a judgement call posing in something that sounds like a clinical diagnosis, so that seems like a bit of posturing in itself.  You seem to believe it's impostor syndrome in this case (you say the OP has "unrealistically high expectations"); I'm not so sure.  A possible alternate point of view is that we can, and should aspire to, do better. Even if all the other departments are doing it too.

Comment: @DonHatch I fully agree. "Clinical diagnosis" was not my intention, just trying to provide a different point of view. Also, by no means, did I intend to suggest that we should not strive to do better.

Comment: I don't *think* imposter syndrome is a clinical diagnosis anyway. If it's not listed in the manuals with definitive diagnostic criteria, then I think you're free to treat it like an English word and call it how you see it. Granted, psychologists may or may not concur with your generalisation from individuals to groups :-)

Comment: "unrealistically high expectations of the research community" It's not really a matter of expectations. We have a community of people that are doing good and bad work to some extent (different in expectations and reality), the problem arises when bad work provides better career opportunities than good work. It seems to be an optimization problem, trying to pretend the most (get impact, stats, projects…) with the least (time and effort) investment on actual research (that someone else will do and nobody will notice). The classical talkers and doers. (I continue)

Comment: The whole thing seems to be designed for pretenders to rule over exploited researchers. But again, if I am right in my perceptions then the problem is not how things are (as compared with expectations), but the direction in which the area will evolve, the forces that drive it and, in short, the optimisation performed by the fitness function, disregarding real merit and promoting pretenders. It doesn't help if other areas of research or aspects of humanity are equally doomed, this is not about comparing, hence it's not the impostor syndrome at a greater scale, IMHO. (I continue)

Comment: Finally, for a small clarification, I have noticed some concern about this question being a rant or psychology based, I think it's relevant in the community [1](/search?q=imposter+syndrome), [2](/search?q=impostor+syndrome) and I can guarantee this is not a rant, I'm not angry at all, I'm disappointed and I'm very concerned (quite worried in fact) about how something as important as research seems to be evolving into lots of useless slides. Maybe we need a war, I don't know about the solutions (and that one is probably stupid), I only wanted to know how "real" the problem may be.

Comment: @Trylks It is an interesting discussion item whether the current incentive model in CS academic research works or not. 5 years ago I would have said it is horribly broken. Now, after a number of quite *positive* experiences, I am not sure anymore how fundamentally broken things are.

Comment: @xLeitix I'd not say it's fundamentally broken, I'd say it's easily corruptible and somewhat corrupted, to a greater or lesser extent depending on the area. Transparency (e.g. open source), as in politics, is not a complete solution but it helps a big deal to keep corruption to a limit, however I don't see it being enforced. You point to positive experiences, I'm having many negative experiences lately and I'm preparing to leave academia. I don't think I'll get much more positive experiences outside, but at least I'll get properly paid (I won't leave otherwise). Point: compare w/ industry.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy this argument.  According to this interpretation, anyone who thinks that anything is not good is suffering from "impostor syndrome by proxy".  If I believe the hamburger place down the street serves bad hamburgers, is that impostor syndrome because I'm comparing it to other hamburgers I've eaten elsewhere that were better?  Your answer really applies only if the issue was specifically that the OP believed his own field was bad compared to other fields, but what he's describing seems more general than that.  It's more like "existential angst" or "lack of faith in humanity".

Comment: I agree with BrenBarn. And also, I don't think Impostor syndrome really has anything to do with this. Impostor syndrome is the false belief that you are not as good as you are made out to be. (If it wasn't false, it'd just be an accurate observation). It sounds here as though OP's colleagues truly pretend to be better than they are. If so - then they are impostors. There's no syndrome, they are simply good old fashioned impostors.

Answer (score 19):

> Is there a name for this feeling?

If there was a name for this feeling, that would imply that this interpretation was just a feeling and wasn't real (and that impostors are not the norm in your field).

You don't believe that your feeling is wrong? Do you?

The actual term you're looking for is probably [cargo cult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult) worshipers and that's not the feeling you have, but the label you'd use to describe the impostors in your field. Richard Feynman even coined the term "cargo cult science", which would imply that he found the majority in such a science to be negligent and most of them potential impostors.

See this entry in Wikipedia on [cargo cult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult):

> The metaphorical use of "cargo cult" was popularized by physicist
>   [Richard Feynman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Feynman) at a 1974 Caltech commencement speech, which later
>   became a chapter in his book [Surely You're Joking, Mr. Feynman!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surely_You%27re_Joking,_Mr._Feynman!), where
>   he coined the phrase ["cargo cult science"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_science) to describe activity that
>   had some of the trappings of real science (such as publication in
>   scientific journals) but lacked a basis in honest experimentation.

See his explanation:

> Following is an excerpt from speech (taken from the book).
>
> In the South Seas there is a cargo cult of people. During the war they
>   saw airplanes land with lots of good materials, and they want the same
>   thing to happen now. So they've arranged to imitate things like
>   runways, to put fires along the sides of the runways, to make a wooden
>   hut for a man to sit in, with two wooden pieces on his head like
>   headphones and bars of bamboo sticking out like antennas--he's the
>   controller--and they wait for the airplanes to land. They're doing
>   everything right. The form is perfect. It looks exactly the way it
>   looked before. But it doesn't work. No airplanes land. So I call these
>   things cargo cult science, because they follow all the apparent
>   precepts and forms of scientific investigation, but they're missing
>   something essential, because the planes don't land.

I suppose that term "cargo cult" could be used as a qualifier for many different areas. For instance, if one was so inclined, one could say "cargo cult academia", or "cargo cult business", and so on...

Answer (score 8):

There actually specific terms/descriptions for what you are experiencing. A few of them are "becoming jaded", "cynical", or - depending on what connotation you'd prefer - "being a realist". This isn't rare, and in general is a side effect of increasing knowledge and experience.

The impostor syndrome and Dunning-Kruger effect is all about a false, biased impression of reality. If you have simply become a cynic, this can become a bias where you come to just assume - and automatically perceive - everyone to be full of it, regardless of whether or not they are.

I have found as I get older and learn more about the world I have to actively fight this bias and assumption that everyone else is full of it, for a simple and all too common reason: people are in fact very often full of it. But let's look at why:

1) As humans we usually do not know what we do not know.

2) Being wrong actually feels exactly like being right, all the way to the very instant we realize our wrongness.

3) There is so much to know about the world that even the most brilliant of us can know only a tiny fraction of what there is to know.

4) The world is complicated and difficult to predict.

5) We have very limited knowledge and ability to predict things, yet we must try to be the masters of our fate and make decisions anyway.

6) Our very physical bodily makeup causes us to be drawn to confidence, and it is often easier to be confident when one knows little. In the words of Bertrand Russel, "The fundamental cause of the trouble is that in the modern world the stupid are cocksure while the intelligent are full of doubt."

7) Bluffing can be a highly effective real-world strategy ("faking it" is often a highly profitable strategy).

...and more.

One of the "treatments" for this bias, if you will, is to remind yourself that while all the above is true, it is just as true of ourselves as it is of others. Most material in the world might very well be chaff, but sometimes you find something of great value, and it isn't good to just plug one's ears and believe nothing or to believe everything.

In other words, work towards a healthy skepticism instead of biased cynicism.

Another issue, dealing with #3 above, is as one learns one quickly develops knowledge that is greater in that specific area then the vast majority of living people. As a simple example, a basic undergraduate course in statistics can give you greater understanding of stats and probability than over 95%+ of all people in the entire world (if you pay attention and think about the material, anyway). With such training you almost immediately notice that nearly every use of statistics in mass media (to say nothing of politics) is wrong, biased, an outright lie, and is at least fundamentally unreliable.

This applies to all of your bullet examples. If we assume most human skills and traits are normally distributed, it suddenly becomes no surprise that most people (managers or otherwise) aren't very good leaders, aren't remarkably honest, tend to exaggerate or make stuff up, and so on.

However, this is all very much the reason why we have science in the first place: to err is human, and oh how oft we err. If we weren't so prone to such errors, we wouldn't need specially developed methods refined over many, many years to help us move towards correctness.

I personally feel that much of the reason for doing science is precisely this realization that most of what we know and believe is probably wrong - and if we are right about anything, it's mostly an accident. And anyone who pretends otherwise is full of it, whether they know it or not - and that includes me, too.

Comment: "it is just as true of ourselves […]". No! I refuse to join this game. I may do research, but I will focus on the quality of the systems I build and not on the venues where I publish the results, actually I may simply publish everything on GitHub. It may be cynicism or the engineer in me pulling back, but as I grow older I am less and less interested in my h-index and the papers, and more on the systems I build. It's not about being famous, wrong or right for me, but about building something that actually works and changes the world or just speaking about some fiction. (Now this is a rant)

Answer (score 7):

A literal answer to a literal form of the question ("is there a name for this?") is "jumping on a bandwagon". :)

CompSci obviously has the blessing/burden of the internet. Probably the only other things equally over-hyped (!?!) are gambling, porn, and various fraud possibilities. The only "completely legal" one of these four is CompSci... but the pressures to fudge are amazingly great.

A comparable bandwagon-corruption (at least in the U.S.) was/is "basic science", esp. math and physics, after WWII, where the "bandwagon" was that this would "save us from the commies" (because building The Bomb had ended WWII... crypto was still secret). So then we had the NSF (National Science Foundation) throwing money at people in math and physics for a while... so NSF funding became a test of credibility, and often at R1 universities nowadays it's impossible to get tenure if y're not vetted by the NSF. But there's not enough money to go around, etc. Unsurprisingly, the NSF has evolved into (pardon my saying-so...) an intensely bureaucratic entity, decisions made in ever-deteriorating fashion.

Similarly, not everyone can successfully author a video-game or internet-app or ... "Market saturation" is another very-relevant descriptor in such situations.

"People tend to jump on(to) band-wagons."

Comment: I agree that the current popularity of CS (both, with students and funding agencies) is a blessing and a curse at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

My two cents: Academia is a very competitive field. Many smart people have to compete for a small number of opportunities, such as (but not limited to) funding, grants, positions, publications on prestigious journals etc. In such a highly competitive environment it is partially necessary to oversell yourself (and your team's) abilities and the importance of your research, otherwise better "salesmen" might easily steal your "spotlight", even when their research might be less significant (according to who is another question) than yours. Of course the more important your research is and the more prestigious your position is and the more weight you carry in the scientific community, allows you not always having to oversell yourself and your abilities. But for the most of us who do not belong to those chosen few, networking, connections and advertising our work is certainly necessary in most of the cases.

In this scenario, how much each one of us oversells himself is a question of personal ethics, upbringing and aspirations. Many go overboard and might fit the negative scenarios you describe. But this type of behavior is not Academia specific and the world is full of such people in any profession. This is a fact of life and you have to "deal with it". In some cases, it is useful that such people actually exist for you to realize what not to become and who you really want to be.

But as a friendly advice, you also need to to calm and vent down. Focus on the positive aspects of life and your work and make your own rules on how you play the game. If your working environment is toxic, minimize its effects by living a full, meaningful life outside Academia. Our work is only a part of who we are and in the long run and there are many more important things in life.

Comment: The specific question seems to be "is there a name for this", which this answer doesn't actually address as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

False humility.

> deprecating one's own sanctity, gifts, talents, and accomplishments
>   for the sake of receiving praise or adulation from others - [Wikipedia on Humility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humility)

The "impostor" doesn't realize how awesome they are, and downplays themselves. When you see that you are smarter and more aware than those around you, but choose to not see this, that is exactly what impostor syndrome is.

[From Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome)

> The impostor syndrome (also spelled imposter syndrome), sometimes
>   called impostor phenomenon or fraud syndrome, is a psychological
>   phenomenon in which people are unable to internalize their
>   accomplishments. Despite external evidence of their competence, those
>   with the syndrome remain convinced that they are frauds and do not
>   deserve the success they have achieved. Proof of success is dismissed
>   as luck, timing, or as a result of deceiving others into thinking they
>   are more intelligent and competent than they believe themselves to
>   be.

In your case, you go on to consider that the others around you should know better. And because you don't accept and represent your true nature that is "smarter"/"more aware" than those around you, you become an impostor like them.

In effect, it is two sides of the same coin. You're looking at those around you as being on one side of the coin, and you on another. The truth is that you're both the same coin.

We are brought up to believe that it is "good" or "right" to be humble. And to an extent, this is truth. I'm not arguing that. However, it seems that you've taken this point to the extreme where you're now falsely humble.

*It is false humility that is the impostor you are looking for.*

Comment: Beautiful unexpected answer, though I'm not sure it's the one I want to settle on / internalize.  "Seeing I'm smarter and more aware than those around me" seems like a dangerous point of view (particularly the "smarter" part), as it can put up a barrier to being able to convince people of anything or change anything.

Comment: As long as you're "trying" to change the others, you'll be running into a wall. If you and them both are suffering from "impostor syndrome" (although on opposite sides of it), then you can lead them out of it by changing it in yourself. When you are no longer an impostor, they will want to stop being impostors as well. Whether it is "dangerous" or not is irrelevant. What is the truth? Test it. Find out for yourself if it's true or not.

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that the only way to effect change is to be a role model.  While I agree that can be an effective tool, I disagree with your assertion that trying to effect change by other means, e.g. pointing out problems and incongruities, is doomed;  I have seen those be effective tools as well.  In any case, my point is that with *any* of these tools, coming at it with the attitude "I'm smarter than them/you" tends to sabatoge the effort, in my belief/experience, and omitting such words opens doors. Thus my resistence to incorporating such words into my model of what's going on.

Comment: Yeah. I'm pretty jaded. I guess I don't care if I come across poorly anymore, and accept that some will write me off simply when I know I'm smarter than them. *shrug*

Answer (score 1):

It is called realistic worldview or healthy criticism. Once one has a sufficient impressive publication list and good political sense, academia can be a very nurturing place for laud incompetence. A friend of mine called it "Stephen Hawking syndrome" referring said authors competence in philosophy.

One problem is the hero worship: "If someone is smart / talented than she/he is competent in anything". At a (or more like beyond) career point most people in academia really believe this and applies to themselves as well as other people judged.