# How to handle students' disrespectfulness?

Tags: teaching, interpersonal-issues, lecture-teaching-method

Related with this problem:
[How to deal with unruly, unengaged students who complain about me?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/151379/how-to-deal-with-unruly-unengaged-students-who-complain-about-me)

After the chairman spoke to me, I started talking to my students softly (more than needed). I tried many other ways to engage them. But the problem is that they think the subject is of no use. I have told them of many applications, but I think they won't realize it now.

But one student is insulting me from day one. He has issue on everything, on assignment.
He is one of the special students of the chairman. He even misbehaved with me during viva. I told the students to not do [rattafication](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/745/Rattafication) (rote memorization) for viva, and to clear their concepts. On the day of viva, when I asked a question about process, I was replied with "I didn't do rattafication".

It was an open book paper and he didn't solve problem correctly.
Instead of accepting his mistake, he was fighting with me that I didn't formulate the question correctly. So I sent that question to my assistant professor. He verified and said that the question is clear.

Now, how should I handle this behaviour of students? Should I talk to the chairman about it, knowing that he is a buddy of the whole class?
Help me, this class is giving me depression.

Edit:
Before exam the students were saying me to decrease the course or consider only the presentation topic as the Oral  examination. Which was against the University Policy. And I rejected their request.

should I complain to the HOD of the department about that student? What will be the conseaquences?

Comment: Your question is very hard for me to follow. It mostly seems like a rant. What have you done differently/learned from the last time you asked a similar question here? Which of the suggestions from the answers did you try?

Comment: This question is hard to follow (what is "viva" or "students of chariman"?). However, I think this situation is best referred to the subject coordinator or course coordinator. If this is givign you depression, you should also seek professional counselling.

Comment: Do you give assignments? How do your students do on those? What is your evidence that they are not interested? Students don't need to be super excited all the time...

Comment: What is a "chairman of a class"? (Google indicates that this might be some leader of a student body. If so, I don't understand how they could have any power over a teacher.)

Comment: If a student misbehaves during the viva, fail them.

Comment: If you are really getting depression, quit the job and go to a professional. Also, how exactly did this guy misbehave now? Because he didn't accept he was wrong? Do you have the absolute power over exams or not?

Comment: I disagree with anonymous people giving advice to quit the job because of depression. A mental health professional should assess if that is appropriate for the situation, which I doubt.

Comment: In what way is the chairman a "buddy" of the whole class? If he is good at his job and gets along well with the students, that's a good thing. You seem to be suggesting that he has an inappropriately close personal relationship with most/all of the students. I could believe he has inappropriate ties to a few students, but all of them?

Comment: Chairman is Head of the department. He is friend of some students in my class, thats why these students are special.

Comment: I don't fail or decrease marks of students just because their behaviour with me. I am allowed to do that but I won't.

Comment: Perhaps related: [How to deal with a student who harasses the (inexperienced) teacher during class?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26842/how-to-deal-with-a-student-who-harasses-the-inexperienced-teacher-during-class)

Comment: See my answer here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/152293/43544 OP has lost all credibility with this student cohort and there's no recovery for that this semester. Suggest OP pass whoever they think they need to and do better next semester.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with a student who harasses the (inexperienced) teacher during class?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26842/how-to-deal-with-a-student-who-harasses-the-inexperienced-teacher-during-class)

Answer (score 3):

**For depression, seek professional help.**

Otherwise,

Few things look alarming to me. The whole of the issue also seems like a conflict and we are only presented with your side which does not include factual statements rather your interpretation of events. (i.e. they are being disrespectful)
Some alarming things on your side:

> After the chairman spoke to me, I started talking to my students softly (more than needed)

demeaning attitude towards your students.

> I tried many other ways to engage them. But the problem is that they think the subject is of no use. I have told them of many applications, but I think they won't realize it now.

I personally think they have the right to be uninterested if the course is mandatory. You can't force-teach people. If you find people's non-engagement distracting, you can try to provide outside of class resources, class videos etc. and make attendance optional.

> But one student is insulting me from day one. He has issue on everything, on assignment.

criticism is not disrespect. He has the right to voice his concern if he thinks there is a problem with the assignment.

> Instead of accepting his mistake, he was fighting with me that I didn't formulate the question correctly.

There is nothing wrong with contesting a grade given. Some, if not most, schools even mandate that there is a session in which students can dispute their exam grades or ask for an independent evaluation.

> So I sent that question to my assistant professor. He verified and said that the question is clear.

Not enough to reach a conclusion.

Overall, your text leave me with the impression that you might very well be at fault here. I can't also say with certainty that your attitude described above is respectful towards your students, at least not on a fundamental level.

About that one student, you might demand a disciplinary hearing in which you get to present your side and he gets to present his side (hopefully). Eventually, an impartial  body of staff decides if he needs to be punished. I don't think with what you have stated here anyone can reach a clear cut conclusion. However, as Bryan Krause pointed out, this might have negative consequences for you if your claims and interpretation of events are not within a reasonable range of the factual events.

Comment: If you didn't see the other side, so it means all is my fault. Or you are unaware of students' behavior in the world. The student that is misbehaving with me is a special person of Head of the department. So the HID on the back giving him support, thats why he can easily say whatever he want. There is a difference between raising an issue and misbehaving. He is misbehaving when I didn't start to teach them. The thing that I realized is that they don't want to study. They need a teacher who do a chit chat with student and thats not me.

Comment: I don’t understand the depression disclaimer. Do you think the OP might be depressed, or the student?

Comment: @gen-z Quote from OP: "Help me, this class is giving me depression."